# Ebike chain vs regular chain for up to 350w Mid Drive

Tags: chain

What are the differences between an ebike chain and a regular bike chain, and would I see an advantage in using an ebike chain for a mid-drive motor 250w-350w? I'm considering the Bafang BBS01B.

The price I can find for KMC e10 is roughly double the KMC x10 but I haven't found any information on what the differences between the two are.

I'm interested in the wear characteristics, strength, and whether a 350w or lower motor would cause any issues on a regular chain that an ebike chain could help with.

Comment: Related  - https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/62948/will-putting-an-e-bike-chain-on-a-traditional-road-bike-give-more-mileage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don’t think you *need* an eBike specific chain. Pro cyclists can achieve 1000W and huge torque in a sprint and they use lightweight road bike chains. Even with a 350W motor you are unlikely to reach similar levels.

It looks like the e10 has beefier pins with "mushroom" riveting. The weight is basically identical (2.34g vs. 2.35g per link) and both have nickel plating.

Doesn’t look like it would make a difference. I think it’s merely a way for KMC to make more money with "eBike specific" parts. The same can be seen with eBike specific tires.

Comment: The tires in particular are actually certified to government standards for low-speed mopeds, it's not purely labelling like other components (although unlikely they actually cost more to manufacture in proportion to the price difference....)